# Database audit trail using kafka change data capture

Tags: apache-kafka, debezium, audit-trail, change-data-capture

I am trying to make an audit trail for a mysql database using kafka, the system should detect any change in the source database and in response inserts a record in destination database in relevant table, making an audit trail for that specific table.I am currently using Debezium for CDC and jdbc sink/source connectors.
Required use case is:

- If a record is inserted in table **students** in source db, a row should be inserted in **students_trail** destination database with old and new values for that row
- same in case of updates and deletes
- there are multiple tables in source db, same above applies for all tables

For now, i have following source and sink connector configurations that replicates any changes happen in the source db to dest db, like an insert would insert same row, and update would update that row, being new to kafka have limited knowledge, how can we achieve the above mentioned scenario for audit logging. thanks

@source.json:

```
{
    "name": "jdbc-source",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "database.hostname": "localhost",
        "database.port": "3306",
        "database.user": "",
        "database.password": "",
        "database.server.name": "localhost",
        "database.whitelist": "dbname",
        "database.server.id": "1234",
        "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "kafka:9092",
        "database.history.kafka.topic": "schema-changes.topicname",
        "transforms": "route",
        "transforms.route.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter",
        "transforms.route.regex": "([^.]+)\\.([^.]+)\\.([^.]+)",
        "transforms.route.replacement": "$3"
    }
}
```

@sink.json:

```
{
    "name": "jdbc-sink",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "topics": "",
        "connection.url": "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306",
        "connection.user": "",
        "connection.password": "",
        "transforms": "unwrap",
        "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState",
        "transforms.unwrap.drop.tombstones": "false",
        "insert.mode": "upsert",
        "auto.create": "true",
        "delete.enabled": "true",
        "auto.evolve": "true",
        "pk.fields": "id",
        "pk.mode": "record_key"
    }
}
```

**Update:**

assuming this is one of the source db tables (student):

```
id  name   birth_date
1   den    2001-09-12
2   jeff   2002-09-02
```

if I insert a new row here e.g 
`3   foo   1999-09-28`

then current settings would insert the same row in dest db in relevant auto created table, but instead i want to have both, before and after state values (josn representation) inserted in a custom schema table (e.g students_trail for this case) which have columns (id, student_id, before, after, timestamp) can be self pre-created or auto create, whichever works. In this case of insertion, new row in dest table should be created and should look like this:

students_trail

```
id   student_id   before   after                 timestamp

98   3            null     "3, foo, 1999-09-28"  current_timestamp
```

In case of insertion before is null, for deletion after is null, for update both before & after states are present, and for each operation a row is inserted in the relevant dest table.

Comment: Well, what data currently gets into the topic and the database? What is the issue?

Comment: @cricket_007 currently the data from debezium connector containing payload "source", "before", "after" row values, with operation (udate, create etc) gets in topic, and current sink config replicates the the source, where i want to have audit trail, with before and after values (just like events coming from binlog in order) to store in db for each operation, instead of replicating it

Comment: Sure, so what data is landing in the sink? Can you show it? And also show what you want instead?

Comment: @cricket_007 have updated the description